# Random array element always missing element 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have code that loads an excel file into a JavaScript array.

```
function Upload() {
        //Reference the FileUpload element.
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
 
        //Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
        if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
 
                //For Browsers other than IE.
                if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
                } else {
                    //For IE Browser.
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var data = "";
                        var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                            data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                        }
                        ProcessExcel(data);
                    };
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
                }
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
        }
    };
    function ProcessExcel(data) {
        //Read the Excel File data.
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
            type: 'binary'
        });
 
        //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
        var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
 
        //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
        excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
                localStorage["excelRows"] = JSON.stringify(excelRows);
                window.open("main screen.html", "Badge Draw - game");

    };
```

On each button click the array is randomized, and displays the element located at [0] in a label. So far so good.

```
    //load the file into array
    memberDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage["excelRows"]);
    
    
    //randomise the array
    for (let i = memberDetails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
         const temp = memberDetails[i];
         memberDetails[i] = memberDetails[j];
         memberDetails[j] = temp;
     }

    //get the values stored at index 0
    memberNumber = memberDetails[0].Badge;
    memberName = memberDetails[0].Name;
     
    memberNumberLabel = document.createElement("label");
    var memberNumberText = document.createTextNode(memberNumber);
    memberNumberLabel.id = "memberNumber";
    memberNumberLabel.appendChild(memberNumberText);
    document.body.appendChild(memberNumberLabel);
    document.getElementById("memberNumber").setAttribute("style", "color: #000000; font-size: XXX-large; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; left: 40%; top: 40%");

    memberNameLabel = document.createElement("label");
    var memberNameText = document.createTextNode(memberName);
    memberNameLabel.id = "memberName";
    memberNameLabel.appendChild(memberNameText);
    document.body.appendChild(memberNameLabel);
    document.getElementById("memberName").setAttribute("style", "color: #000000; font-size: xxx-large; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; left: 40%; top: 60%");

}
```

There are only 6 elements in the array (testing). However, I have noticed after hundreds of tests, that element located at [0] BEFORE randomization never appears. I can print the array and all elements are present, however, I can never call element [0].

I'm sure its a logic error but I can't debug.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: irrelevant. Once it is added to the array, there is an element [0]. besides, i can writeln all the elements including element[0]. However, never appears after randomization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shuffling the array using

```js
for (let i = memberDetails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    const temp = memberDetails[i];
    memberDetails[i] = memberDetails[j];
    memberDetails[j] = temp;
}
```

To see the issue with the logic, consider an array with only 2 elements, and dry run the loop. We would iterate from 1 to 0.

When i is 1, `Math.random() * i` would return a value between 0 and 1, but since we are doing `Math.floor()`, it would always floor it to 0 (Since `Math.random()` never returns 1). We are then swapping the 0th element with 1st.

When i is 0, `Math.random() * i` is 0, so we swap the now 0th element with itself.

This is the error in the logic, you may want to replace `floor` with `round`

**But!**

If all you are looking to do is to pick a random element from the array, it is sufficient to do

```js
const randomMember = memberDetails[Math.floor(Math.random() * memberDetails.length]
```

instead of shuffling the entire array.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was pulling out my what little hair I have left. Just a note: Legally every "draw" must include every number and must be random. Picture tickets in a barrel, when I draw a ticket and find a winner, the ticket goes back into the barrel, is shuffled and the next draw begins. Hence the shuffling of the array on each drawn.

Comment: @WayneMcfayden That's fine, but make sure you do not load the array from localStorage during the next shuffle, otherwise you would begin with the original array.